# Shell script launching GUI emacs from wrong directory

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

So I have what I thought was a trivial shell script sitting on my $PATH which is meant to enable me to open files in GUI emacs from the command line.  Here's the entire script (which is just named `em`)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"

emacsup=$(pidof emacs)

if [ ! "$emacsup" ]
then
    emacs "$@" &
else
    emacsclient -nc "$@"
fi
```

(The echo is for debugging purposes, to make sure I'm working in the directory I think I'm working in.)

But this doesn't work correctly for the case where emacs isn't previously running.  If I go to, say, `~/foo/` and attempt to open a file that already exists, say, `bar.txt` by navigating to that directory and using `em bar.txt` I'll get an echo that shows the script is running from the correct working directory, but when emacs opens, the buffer points to `bar.txt` in my home directory.  In addition, the `&` part of the command doesn't work right---I expect that to return me a command line, but that doesn't happen.

The script works correctly when emacs is already open.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems you are running another script. To make sure run `type em`.

Comment: Both `type` and `which` point to the right script

Comment: Run “bash -x /full/path/to/em bar.txt” and post results

Comment: I suggest adding `command -v emacs` to your script, and confirming that it's what you think it is.